# Open link in new TAB (WebBrowser Control)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, tabcontrol

Does anybody know how to click on a link in the WebBrowser control in a WinForms application and then have that link open in a new tab inside my TabControl?

I've been searching for months, seen many tutorials/articles/code samples but it seems as though nobody has ever tried this in C# before.

Any advice/samples are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm someone else who is having trouble with ie opening whenever i click on a web page link within my own browser. Tried all of the above but no luck, the first reply by Robert
I added ExtendedWebBrowser in design mode, but i'm still getting the red line underneath (InitialTabBrowser) on the last line of code, and the warning of 'InitialTabBroswer does not exist in the current context'. Any more tips/advice would be great.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Based on your comments, I understand that you want to trap the "Open In New Window" action for the WebBrowser control, and override the default behavior to open in a new tab inside your application instead.

To accomplish this reliably, you need to get at the NewWindow2 event, which exposes ppDisp (a settable pointer to the WebBrowser control that should open the new window).
All of the other potential hacked together solutions (such as obtaining the last link selected by the user before the OpenWindow event) are not optimal and are bound to fail in corner cases.

Luckily, there is a (relatively) simple way of accomplishing this while still using the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control as a base. All you need to do is extend the WebBrowser and intercept the NewWindow2 event while providing public access to the ActiveX Instance (for passing into ppDisp in new tabs). This has been done before, and Mauricio Rojas has an excellent example with a complete working class "ExtendedWebBrowser":

http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2008/09/18/newwindow2-events-in-the-c-webbrowsercontrol.aspx

Once you have the ExtendedWebBrowser class, all you need to do is setup handlers for NewWindow2 and point ppDisp to a browser in a new tab. Here's an example that I put together:

```
    private void InitializeBrowserEvents(ExtendedWebBrowser SourceBrowser)
    {
        SourceBrowser.NewWindow2 += new EventHandler<NewWindow2EventArgs>(SourceBrowser_NewWindow2);
    }

    void SourceBrowser_NewWindow2(object sender, NewWindow2EventArgs e)
    {

        TabPage NewTabPage = new TabPage()
        {
            Text = "Loading..."
        };

        ExtendedWebBrowser NewTabBrowser = new ExtendedWebBrowser()
        {
            Parent = NewTabPage,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Tag = NewTabPage
        };

        e.PPDisp = NewTabBrowser.Application;
        InitializeBrowserEvents(NewTabBrowser);

        Tabs.TabPages.Add(NewTabPage);
        Tabs.SelectedTab = NewTabPage;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        InitializeBrowserEvents(InitialTabBrowser);

    }
```

(Assumes TabControl named "Tabs" and initial tab containing child control docked ExtendedWebBrowser named "InitialWebBrowser")

Don't forget to unregister the events when the tabs are closed!

Comment: Thank you very much Robert for the sample code and the link :-) I do have a couple of questions, I added a class and called it ExtendedWebBrowser.cs and then added your sample code to the Form1.cs file and it gives me the following error when I try to debug: "Argument '1' cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser to 'ExtendedWebBrowser'." And the blue squigly line appears below the following line of code: InitializeBrowserEvents(InitialTabBrowser);     Do you know what that is?

Comment: Make sure your InitialWebBrowser is of type "ExtendedWebBrowser" - It looks like you are still using the "WebBrowser". To add the ExtendedWebBrowser, look in your toolbox. You should see it towards the top with a small gear symbol next to it. This is what you should add to your form in design mode for the InitialWebBrowser control.

Comment: For some weird reason new window is still opens in external web browser for me, event though I use ExtendedWebBrowser and using NewWindow2 event to create new web browser.

Answer (score 4):

```
private Uri _MyUrl;    

System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
browser.Navigating += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(browser_Navigating);


void browser_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    _MyUrl = e.Url;
    e.Cancel;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sshow, that was very helpful, though I am trying to get the url that is sent to the new browser window so that i can stop the new browser from opening and just open that url in a new tab in my own browser? For example when i right-click on a link and select Open in New Window i don't want it to open in a new IE i want it to open in a new tab in my own webbrowser

Comment: Maybe you can override the ContextMenu for the "Open in New Window" button. I've never done such a thing before. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

The following code works, just follow the first reply for creating the ExtendedWebBrowser class.

I'm using this to open a new tab but it also works to open a new window using your browser and not IE.

Hope it helps.

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (current_tab_count == 10) return;
        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage("Loading...");
        tabpages.Add(tabPage);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
        current_tab_count++;
        ExtendedWebBrowser browser = new ExtendedWebBrowser();
        InitializeBrowserEvents(browser);
        webpages.Add(browser);
        browser.Parent = tabPage;
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
        browser.DocumentTitleChanged += new EventHandler(Browser_DocumentTitleChanged);
        browser.Navigated += Browser_Navigated;
        browser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = true;
public void InitializeBrowserEvents(ExtendedWebBrowser browser)
    {
        browser.NewWindow2 += new EventHandler<ExtendedWebBrowser.NewWindow2EventArgs>(Browser_NewWindow2);
    }

    void Browser_NewWindow2(object sender, ExtendedWebBrowser.NewWindow2EventArgs e)
    {

        if (current_tab_count == 10) return;
        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage("Loading...");
        tabpages.Add(tabPage);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
        current_tab_count++;
        ExtendedWebBrowser browser = new ExtendedWebBrowser();
        webpages.Add(browser);
        browser.Parent = tabPage;
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
        browser.DocumentTitleChanged += new EventHandler(Browser_DocumentTitleChanged);
        browser.Navigated += Browser_Navigated;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage;
        browser.Navigate(textBox.Text);

        {
            e.PPDisp = browser.Application;
            InitializeBrowserEvents(browser); 
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I did a bit of research on this topic and one does not need to do all the COM plumbing that is present in the ExtendedWebBrowser class, as that code is already present in the generated Interop.SHDocVw.  As such, I was able to use the more natural construct below to subscribe to the NewWindow2 event.  In Visual Studio I had to add a reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls".

```
    using SHDocVw;
    ...

    internal WebBrowserSsoHost(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser,...)
    {
        ParameterHelper.ThrowOnNull(webBrowser, "webBrowser");
        ...

        (webBrowser.ActiveXInstance as WebBrowser).NewWindow2 += OnNewWindow2;
    }

    private void OnNewWindow2(ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MyTabPage tabPage = TabPageFactory.CreateNewTabPage();
        tabPage.SetBrowserAsContent(out ppDisp);
    }
```

Please read http://bit.ly/IDWm5A for more info.  This is page #5 in the series, for a complete understanding I had to go back and read pages 3 -> 5.

Comment: What's all this? How to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You simply cancel the new window event and handle the navigation and tab stuff yourself.

Here is a fully working example. This assumes you have a tabcontrol and at least 1 tab page in place.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace stackoverflow2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.webBrowser1.NewWindow += WebBrowser1_NewWindow;
            this.webBrowser1.Navigated += Wb_Navigated;
            this.webBrowser1.DocumentText=
             "<html>"+
             "<head><title>Title</title></head>"+
             "<body>"+
             "<a href = 'http://www.google.com' target = 'abc' > test </a>"+
             "</body>"+
             "</html>";
        }
        private void WebBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true; //stop normal new window activity

            //get the url you were trying to navigate to
            var url= webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.GetAttribute("href");

            //set up the tabs
            TabPage tp = new TabPage();
            var wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Navigated += Wb_Navigated;
            wb.Size = this.webBrowser1.Size;
            tp.Controls.Add(wb);
            wb.Navigate(url);
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(tp);
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tp;
        }

        private void Wb_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = (sender as WebBrowser).DocumentTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There is no tabbing in the web browser control, therefor you need to handle the tabs yourself. Add a tab control above the web browser control and create new web browser controls when new tabs are being opened. Catch and cancel when the user opens new windows and open new tabs instead.