# Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' to 'ExtendedWebBrowser'

Tags: c#, debugging, browser

I am trying to debug my cute little application here and it won't let me :( When I click Debug, I get two errors, the first one is:

**Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.InitializeBrowserEvents(ExtendedWebBrowser)' has some invalid arguments**

and the second:

**Error 2   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' to 'ExtendedWebBrowser'**

---

Can anybody please help me solve this? I have no idea what this means.

I don't know if this is enough information for you so please do say if more info is needed and I will be glad to post more.

Thank you,
Baeltazor.

Edit: I'm guessing that once I get rid of the second error, the first one will go away with it...

Comment: You would need to post what is ExtendedWebBrowser, which is not standard part of .NET. Also, I have no respect for people who don't even read the error message. Sorry.

Comment: Why would you assume that someone hasn't read the error? And to be quite honest, I don't give a rats ass whether you respect me or not.

Comment: I assume that if it is your project, as you wrote, you would know which functions take what type of arguments. The error message is pretty clear about what is happening, though I applaud Jon Skeet for describing it in even more detail.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a method with this signature:

```
InitializeBrowserEvents(ExtendedWebBrowser x)
```

and you're trying to call it like this:

```
WebBrowser wb = new ExtendedWebBrowser (); // Or whatever
InitializeBrowserEvents(wb);
```

That's not going to work due to the type of the `wb` variable. You can *either* change the signature of `InitializeBrowserEvents` like this:

```
InitializeBrowserEvents(WebBrowser x)
```

or change the type of the argument you're trying to pass in. We can't tell which would be more appropriate without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Now, if you have linked to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/c-open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control) and the [respective answer](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2008/09/18/newwindow2-events-in-the-c-webbrowsercontrol.aspx) it would be easier to assume that you actually placed a wrong control on the form in designer. You want to compile the project with ExtendedWebBrowser first, then add it to controls toolbox in the designer (if not done automatically) and replace your WebBrowser control with it.