# WebBrowser control problem

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using this code:

```
//I store the website urls in mylist
list<string> mylist=new list<string>();     

foreach(string webname in mylist)
{
    wbmain.navigate(webname);
}
```

But there is a problem in the code is the wbmain.navigate the first url and doesn't wait for first url to open and it opens second ..........and it shows the last url.

Finally I see the last page.

How can I if check the first url is opened and wait for 15 sec and open the second page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

foreach(string webName in myList)
{
    wbmain.navigate(webName);

    // Sleep for 15 seconds.
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
}
```

...the example assumes you're working in WinForms.

**There is a better (and correct) way to wait until the page has loaded**. The WebBrowser control has a `DocumentCompleted` Event that you could use to reload a new address each time the current page finishes loading. Check the link for the MSDN documentation:

[WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx)

Comment: Thread.Sleep would block the webbrowser because it is trying to notify the main thread of the Navigating event, and the notification is blocked by Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @Sheng The example was quick and off the top of my head which is why I posted the better (and correct) way to wait for the page to finish loading.

Answer (score 0):

You could also follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/c-open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control) and open each in a new tab.