# How to capture context menu "view source" click in c# WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, contextmenu

I am trying to intercept a click on the "view source" item on C# WebBrowser's context menu. The default click opens the web page's source in notepad, but I would like, to cancel the default action and open my own form with the source code in a RichTextBox, which is a part of the opening window.

Thanks to Robert I managed to intercept opening right-clicked links in new tabs instead of new windows ([[Open link in new TAB (WebBrowser Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control)), but I was unable to capture the "view source" click.

I would appreciate any advices and solutions to my problem.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but one way to do it is to reference `Microsoft.mshtml` and read the source like:

```
var doc = yourBrowserControl.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
txtSource.Text = doc.body.innerHTML;
```

However, this method does not give you the complete source (for example, the HEAD section of the source is completely missing).