# open picture in new tab, same as if do right click - View Image in firefox (WatiN)

Tags: c#, watin

I need to open image in new tab exactly as it's being done by clicking right button on it and then selecting View Image in firefox. Copying pic url and using browser.Goto doesn't give me the result i need due to some tricky javascript. Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Looks like similar to [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control

Comment: This looks like similar to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control

Comment: @PSJoshi yeah, looks like that but i need to handle image, cannot click it like a link. Will ask in that thread too, maybe they can help too

Comment: Can you explain that "tricky javascript"?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, some answer for reference only.

Get the src attribute for the image you are looking for and then open a new instance of IE with that address (you will probably need to append the base website address plus whatever there is in the src attribute for the image you are looking for. Some code for that:

```
Image btnLogin = Window.Image(Find.ByName("TheImageNameOrAnyOtherAttribute"));
string imageAddress = btnLogin.GetAttributeValue("src");

var newBrowser = new IE();
newBrowser.GoTo("http://www.somesite.com/"+imageAddress);
```