# WebBrowser Control (VB.NET) new tab

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have a problem with WebBrowser Control in vb.net (Windows form application) . The problem is when i click on a hyperlink that opens it new tab , it opens new Internet Explorer window? How can I make to open new tab in my tab control instead of Internet Explorer ? I searched online , but i only found results for c# . For example this result [Open link in new TAB (WebBrowser Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control)

Comment: If you want to get somewhere as a VB.Net programmer I would suggest that you at least learn to read C# code. The differences aren't that large and you will be able to quickly understand and convert (or just use the C# code in another assembly that you call from VB.Net) most samples you find on the internet.

Comment: Well , Im still beginner in VB.NET . After  I get a good knowledge in vb.net i will learn C# .

Comment: Well the solution described in your link is using com interop to extend the `WebBrowser`-control with a new event which is quite advanced. Then they have their own tab-control (there isn't one built in into the `WebBrowser`-control) to open a new one. I don't have time to write it all up for you but the easiest would be to take the suggested extension code and put in your own assembly and then use that from VB.Net.

Comment: Ok , thank you for explanation . But i still see it complicated :( .

Answer (score 0):

The code in question from the other link.........

```
Private Sub InitializeBrowserEvents(SourceBrowser As ExtendedWebBrowser)
SourceBrowser.NewWindow2 += New EventHandler(Of NewWindow2EventArgs)(AddressOf SourceBrowser_NewWindow2)
End Sub
'
Private Sub SourceBrowser_NewWindow2(sender As Object, e As NewWindow2EventArgs)
Dim NewTabPage As New TabPage() With { Key .Text = "Loading..." }
Dim NewTabBrowser As New ExtendedWebBrowser() With { Key .Parent = NewTabPage, Key .Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Key .Tag = NewTabPage }
  '
  e.PPDisp = NewTabBrowser.Application
  InitializeBrowserEvents(NewTabBrowser)
  '
  Tabs.TabPages.Add(NewTabPage)
  Tabs.SelectedTab = NewTabPage
End Sub
'
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  InitializeBrowserEvents(InitialTabBrowser)
End Sub
```

Please note, I used THIS link to convert code...

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=2183e979-2b56-4c82-a7d5-c0822e7f0bca

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to add my Tabbed_EI .dll to your tool box and link your application button clicks and other events to Tabbed_EI's public/global variables, objects, and Subs. Located [here](http://amerigoware1.wix.com/amerigoware#!tabbed-browser/c1pb6)

You can otherwise use the Webbrowser.newWindow event and add
"e.cancel = true"