# Enable right-click's "Open Link in New Tab" in webbrowser control

Tags: tabs, c#-3.0, webbrowser-control

I have developed a web browser, but "Open Link in New Tab" option in my right-click is disabled .

I want to enable the right-click's "Open Link in New Tab". Then open the page within my application, and not in internet explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The WebBrowser control does not support multi-tab navigation. You'll have to create your own tabs (for example, using the TabControl control) which would contain instances of WebBrowser. That is explained here:
[Open link in new TAB (WebBrowser Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control)

Then, you'll need to customize the context menu of your WebBrowser by adding the "Open In New Tab" action. That action will trigger your own implementation of multi-tab navigation. This is explained here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx