# how to create "open in new tab" contextmenustrip in C# webbrowser?

Tags: c#

I'm building a web browser in C#. I want to create my own contextmenustrip when right click but I don't know how to it. Can you help me to solve this "open in new tab"?

Comment: We would need to know more about your current application structure to help you. For example.. does your `WebBrowser` control currently reside in a `TabControl`?

Comment: yes. my app is a multitabs browser. I mean I want to know how does "open in new tab" work and create my own Contextmenustrip include "open in new tab"

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the context.

If you are building this on top of Windows Forms for example, you can trap the mouse down event and check for a right click, after which you can run any code you want, including opening a "context menu strip"

```
this.browser.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.browserpanel_MouseDown);
```

In browserpanel_MouseDown you can then check for

```
e.Button == MouseButtons.Right
```

Comment: Thank you! you might misunderstand what I mean. I want to create my own "open in new tab" like in IE, Chrome, Firefox....

Comment: If you are using the build in ContextMenuStrip, you can add BrowserContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("open in new tab", null, newTabClickHandler);

If that is not what you meant, you might have to explain in more detail what you already have and what part you are looking to figure out.

Comment: BrowserContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("open in new tab", null, newTabClickHandler); is what I meant but I dont know whatnewTabClickHandler must do...Sorry, my English is too bad.

Comment: You will have to tell us a little more about your structure, like Simon asked already. How do you load your browser control and what is your container?

In the meantime you can also check another stackoverflow response that might be already answering your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control?rq=1