# Initialize ExtendedWebBrowser in VB.NET, problem parsing from C# to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, winapi, webbrowser-control

Following a previous answer [open link in new tab WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control/1383888).

And thanks to Mauricio Rojas who posted a good example in C#:
[Extended WebBrowser Control for C#](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2008/09/18/Extended-WebBrowser-Control-SeriesNewWindow2-Events-in-the-C-WebBrowserControl.aspx).

I'm trying to convert code provided for C# to VB.NET, but I have a problem:
I don't understand why, when I try to implement the `DWebBrowserEvents2` Interface in the `WebBrowserExtendedEvents` Class, Visual Studio gives me an Error:

> *Class WebBrowserExtendedEvents must implements Sub NewWindow2(ByRef pDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean) for the Interface
> DWebBrowserEvents2*

It seems to me that I've correctly implemented that Method, in the Class and the Interface.

> Note: I though about removing parts of code not related to the question, as [jmcilhinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584183/jmcilhinney) suggested, but since I didn't find, in the Web, clear examples of `ExtendedWebBrowser` for VB.Net, I decided to leave the full code, for the benefit of others.

Here the full code translated to VB.Net

```vb
'First define a new EventArgs class to contain the newly exposed data
Public Class NewWindow2EventArgs
    Inherits CancelEventArgs

    Private _ppDisp As Object
    Public Property PPDisp As Object
        Get
            Return _ppDisp
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            _ppDisp = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByRef ppDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.ppDisp = Me.ppDisp
        Me.Cancel = cancel
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DocumentCompleteEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Private _ppDisp As Object
    Public Property PPDisp As Object
        Get
            Return _ppDisp
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            _ppDisp = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _url As Object
    Public Property Url As Object
        Get
            Return _url
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            _url = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal ppDisp As Object, ByVal url As Object)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.ppDisp = Me.ppDisp
        Me.url = Me.url
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CommandStateChangeEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Private _command As Long
    Public Property Command As Long
        Get
            Return _command
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
            _command = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _enable As Boolean
    Public Property Enable As Boolean
        Get
            Return _enable
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _enable = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal command As Long, ByRef enable As Boolean)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.command = Me.command
        Me.enable = Me.enable
    End Sub

End Class

'Extend the WebBrowser control
Public Class ExtendedWebBrowser
    Inherits WebBrowser

    Private cookie As AxHost.ConnectionPointCookie

    Private Shadows events As WebBrowserExtendedEvents

    'This method will be called to give you a chance to create your own event sink
    Protected Overrides Sub CreateSink()
        'MAKE SURE TO CALL THE BASE or the normal events won't fire
        MyBase.CreateSink()
        Me.events = New WebBrowserExtendedEvents(Me)
        Me.cookie = New AxHost.ConnectionPointCookie(Me.ActiveXInstance, Me.events, GetType(DWebBrowserEvents2))
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Application As Object
        Get
            Dim axWebBrowser As IWebBrowser2 = CType(Me.ActiveXInstance, IWebBrowser2)
            If (Not (axWebBrowser) Is Nothing) Then
                Return axWebBrowser.Application
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If

        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub DetachSink()
        If (Not (Me.cookie) Is Nothing) Then
            Me.cookie.Disconnect()
            Me.cookie = Nothing
        End If

        MyBase.DetachSink()
    End Sub

    'This new event will fire for the NewWindow2
    Public Event NewWindow2 As EventHandler(Of NewWindow2EventArgs)

    Protected Sub OnNewWindow2(ByRef ppDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean)
        'Dim h As EventHandler(Of NewWindow2EventArgs) = NewWindow2

        Dim args As NewWindow2EventArgs = New NewWindow2EventArgs(ppDisp, cancel)
        If Not IsNothing(NewWindow2Event) Then
            RaiseEvent NewWindow2(Me, args)
        End If

        'Pass the cancellation chosen back out to the events
        'Pass the ppDisp chosen back out to the events
        cancel = args.Cancel
        ppDisp = args.PPDisp
    End Sub

    'This new event will fire for the DocumentComplete
    Public Event DocumentComplete As EventHandler(Of DocumentCompleteEventArgs)

    Protected Sub OnDocumentComplete(ByVal ppDisp As Object, ByVal url As Object)
        'Dim h As EventHandler(Of DocumentCompleteEventArgs) = DocumentComplete
        Dim args As DocumentCompleteEventArgs = New DocumentCompleteEventArgs(ppDisp, url)
        If Not IsNothing(DocumentCompleteEvent) Then
            RaiseEvent DocumentComplete(Me, args)
        End If

        'Pass the ppDisp chosen back out to the events
        ppDisp = args.PPDisp
        'I think url is readonly
    End Sub

    'This new event will fire for the CommandStateChange
    Public Event CommandStateChange As EventHandler(Of CommandStateChangeEventArgs)

    Protected Sub OnCommandStateChange(ByVal command As Long, ByRef enable As Boolean)
        'Dim h As EventHandler(Of CommandStateChangeEventArgs) = CommandStateChange
        Dim args As CommandStateChangeEventArgs = New CommandStateChangeEventArgs(command, enable)
        If Not IsNothing(CommandStateChangeEvent) Then
            RaiseEvent CommandStateChange(Me, args)
        End If

    End Sub

    'This class will capture events from the WebBrowser
    Public Class WebBrowserExtendedEvents
        Inherits System.Runtime.InteropServices.StandardOleMarshalObject

        '******************* HERE THE ERROR ********************
        Implements DWebBrowserEvents2
        '*******************************************************

        Private _Browser As ExtendedWebBrowser

        Public Sub New(ByVal browser As ExtendedWebBrowser)
            MyBase.New()
            Me._Browser = browser
        End Sub

        'Implement whichever events you wish
        Public Sub NewWindow2(ByRef pDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean)
            Me._Browser.OnNewWindow2(pDisp, cancel)
        End Sub

        'Implement whichever events you wish
        Public Sub DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, ByRef url As Object)
            Me._Browser.OnDocumentComplete(pDisp, url)
        End Sub

        'Implement whichever events you wish
        Public Sub CommandStateChange(ByVal command As Long, ByVal enable As Boolean)
            Me._Browser.OnCommandStateChange(command, enable)
        End Sub

    End Class

    <ComImport(), _
     Guid("34A715A0-6587-11D0-924A-0020AFC7AC4D"), _
     InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch), _
     TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FHidden)> _
    Public Interface DWebBrowserEvents2

        <DispId(105)> _
        Sub CommandStateChange(ByVal command As Long, ByVal enable As Boolean)

        <DispId(259)> _
        Sub DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, ByRef URL As Object)

        <DispId(251)> _
        Sub NewWindow2(ByRef pDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean)

    End Interface

    <ComImport(), _
     Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11d0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E"), _
     TypeLibType((TypeLibTypeFlags.FOleAutomation _
                Or (TypeLibTypeFlags.FDual Or TypeLibTypeFlags.FHidden)))> _
    Public Interface IWebBrowser2

        <DispId(100)> _
        Sub GoBack()

        <DispId(101)> _
        Sub GoForward()

        <DispId(102)> _
        Sub GoHome()

        <DispId(103)> _
        Sub GoSearch()

        <DispId(104)> _
        Sub Navigate(ByVal Url As String, ByRef flags As Object, ByRef targetFrameName As Object, ByRef postData As Object, ByRef headers As Object)

        <DispId(-550)> _
        Sub Refresh()

        <DispId(105)> _
        Sub Refresh2(ByRef level As Object)

        <DispId(106)> _
        Sub [Stop]()

        <DispId(200)> _
        ReadOnly Property Application As Object

        <DispId(201)> _
        ReadOnly Property Parent As Object

        <DispId(202)> _
        ReadOnly Property Container As Object

        <DispId(203)> _
        ReadOnly Property Document As Object

        <DispId(204)> _
        ReadOnly Property TopLevelContainer As Boolean

        <DispId(205)> _
        ReadOnly Property Type As String

        <DispId(206)> _
        Property Left As Integer

        <DispId(207)> _
        Property Top As Integer

        <DispId(208)> _
        Property Width As Integer

        <DispId(209)> _
        Property Height As Integer

        <DispId(210)> _
        ReadOnly Property LocationName As String

        <DispId(211)> _
        ReadOnly Property LocationURL As String

        <DispId(212)> _
        ReadOnly Property Busy As Boolean

        <DispId(300)> _
        Sub Quit()

        <DispId(301)> _
        Sub ClientToWindow(ByRef pcx As Integer, ByRef pcy As Integer)

        <DispId(302)> _
        Sub PutProperty(ByVal _property As String, ByVal vtValue As Object)

        <DispId(303)> _
        Function GetProperty(ByVal _property As String) As Object

        <DispId(0)> _
        ReadOnly Property Name As String

        <DispId(-515)> _
        ReadOnly Property HWND As Integer

        <DispId(400)> _
        ReadOnly Property FullName As String

        <DispId(401)> _
        ReadOnly Property Path As String

        <DispId(402)> _
        Property Visible As Boolean

        <DispId(403)> _
        Property StatusBar As Boolean

        <DispId(404)> _
        Property StatusText As String

        <DispId(405)> _
        Property ToolBar As Integer

        <DispId(406)> _
        Property MenuBar As Boolean

        <DispId(407)> _
        Property FullScreen As Boolean

        <DispId(500)> _
        Sub Navigate2(ByRef URL As Object, ByRef flags As Object, ByRef targetFrameName As Object, ByRef postData As Object, ByRef headers As Object)

        <DispId(503)> _
        Sub ShowBrowserBar(ByRef pvaClsid As Object, ByRef pvarShow As Object, ByRef pvarSize As Object)

        <DispId(-525)> _
        ReadOnly Property ReadyState As WebBrowserReadyState

        <DispId(550)> _
        Property Offline As Boolean

        <DispId(551)> _
        Property Silent As Boolean

        <DispId(552)> _
        Property RegisterAsBrowser As Boolean

        <DispId(553)> _
        Property RegisterAsDropTarget As Boolean

        <DispId(554)> _
        Property TheaterMode As Boolean

        <DispId(555)> _
        Property AddressBar As Boolean

        <DispId(556)> _
        Property Resizable As Boolean
    End Interface
End Class
```

Comment: Firstly, why do you have all those classes inside a module? No. That would be equivalent to the C# code having all the classes inside a static class. I don't see that in the C# and it would be ludicrous, so doing the equivalent in VB is just as ludicrous. It is rare that declaring one type inside another type is a good thing. Only do it if you have a specific reason to do so. If you don't know if you have a specific reason, you don't.

Comment: Secondly, please don't just post all the code you have. Post ONLY the relevant code. If you issue is the `WebBrowserExtendedEvents` class then that's the class you need to show us. The others just make our life harder by obfuscating the issue. If would also help to provide the corresponding C# code in your post, not as an external link.

Comment: You're missing, e.g., `Implements DWebBrowserEvents2.CommandStateChange` in the methods (a VB.Net thing). As in: `Public Sub NewWindow2(ByRef pDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean) Implements DWebBrowserEvents2.NewWindow2`. Follow jmcilhinney's advice, in relation to module usage.

Comment: @jmcilhinney first of all "It is rare that declaring one type inside another type is a good thing. Only do it if you have a specific reason to do so. If you don't know if you have a specific reason, you don't" is an opinionated view. What he does with 'modules' is legal in the language. If anything he did caused problems, pinpoint those problems and let him learn from this. Giving empty advises like "never do that until you have reasons" is pointless, as it doesn't allow to learn anything except for a rule without rationale.

Comment: As a side note (not so aside), those Marshaling parts you have removed, as `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)`, put them back. `<In,Out>` is not required.

Comment: @jmcilhinney and second,the code he posted IS COMPLETE. Yes, it's more than a few lines, but the code of the code is the ExtendedWebBrowser class, and the rest of the classes in the module are other user-code classes needed to compile ExtendedWebBrowser. So that's a pretty much complete minimal example. It might be shortened a bit, but right now it certainly is not "too long". In case you disagree,yeah, we can disagree - "code length" is a subjective thing :) Anyways,there's also the Module thing. VBA/VB.Net are a bit odd. I'm totally NOT surprised to see a Module used to group code like this.

Comment: @Jimi make it an answer please!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, *"[...] is an opinionated view"*. Really? I would suggest that it is objective fact that nesting types is rarely a good thing. You could say that it's opinion that you should not do things that are at pointless at best and serve only to complicate your code but I would also say that it is an objective fact that anyone who has a different opinion is a fool. Using a module here serves no useful purpose so it should not be done. Encouraging people to continue to do useless and at least slightly harmful things is doing them a disservice.

Comment: @Marcello, none of that makes any sense I'm afraid. *"the code is much neater than putting dozens and dozens of classes all in the same class"*. You don't put dozens of classes inside another class in the first place, so you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Like I said, don't nest ANY types without a specific reason, which means class in class, class in module or any other combination. *"by putting a module I can call the Class directly, without putting any prefix"*. That is also a problem that have imagined. There is no "prefix" required regardless.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, *"jmcilhinney's point is that you should use namespaces see here instead of modules"*. No it wasn't. My point was exactly what I said: don't nest types without a reason. We shouldn't be doing anything that complicates code without a reason. Whether or not namespaces should be used is a different matter. Everything is already in the default namespace and that is generally enough for simple projects. All those types are already in a namespace so you wouldn't add an extra one unless you have a reason to do so.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, *"not everybody is born with the knowledge about namespaces"*. It's a good job that my comments had nothing to do with namespaces then, isn't it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: So, let's see what the author of the code said: `This way, in Visual Studio, the code is much neater than putting dozens and dozens of classes all in the same class. Also by putting a module I can call the Class directly, without putting any prefix that I should put if I programmed as you would like` - holy moly, sounds just like tidying the code in a namespaces, but just using modules/classes instead of namespaces + `using` keyword&etc. My, I must have been clairvoyant or something, who else could guess that just by reading the code!

Comment: @jmcilhinney, for your second point, yes you are right.

Honestly, I really thought about your solution, that of putting the code in C # and that in VB.Net.

But since honestly, I don't have all the necessary knowledge to fully understand Mauricio Rojas's code, and I didn't know if that piece of code was indirectly necessary, I preferred to post the entire translation.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, *"sounds just like tidying the code in a namespaces"*. Not really. Sounds misguided in a number of ways, actually. Anyway, I provided accurate information based on what was presented. If you think that you can provide better information, by all means do so. I'll keep doing what I'm doing and not make assumptions about why someone is doing the wrong thing. If they want advice on how to accomplish something the right way, they can ask a question about that. I'm fairly sure there are sites around where you can ask programming questions.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, i appreciate your help, (even if you appear just a bit 'rude' in your mode to explain others your opinion).

But it's also true that not all visitors are at your level of code comprension.

You shouldn't assume 'you or someone with your knowledge' would have answered me.

If someone with less knowledge than yours, would have answered me, he certainly would have liked to read full code.

Comment: *"he certainly would have liked to read full code"*. I very much doubt that. My experience is that pretty much everyone would like to read as little code as possible. By posting so much code, you made it harder to focus on the relevant code. Anyone who knows the solution to this issue would know just from the class and just the method in question. Anyone who wouldn't know the answer from that wouldn't know the answer. An appropriate example in this case would be one that compiles but for the error message in question. That requires far less code than you posted.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Thanks j mcilhinney for your suggestions.

Following your advice i was next to remove unnecessary code, but Jimy found another issue in the code translation.

Since my General question is 'Extended WebBrowser, ...problem parsing from C# to VB.NET' and also this new code suggestion regards part of full code, i leave all code, in way can be usefull for someone will need in future.

But as i told you i appreciate a lot your help. You teach me for free, and you spend your time, helping me to learn on how coding better. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.Net requires that an [Implements keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/implements-clause) is added to the members that implement the corresponding Interface members.

Your `WebBrowserExtendedEvents` class defines the implementation but its members are  missing the Implements keyword, that's all. For example:

```
Public Sub NewWindow2(ByRef pDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean)
    Me._Browser.OnNewWindow2(pDisp, cancel)
End Sub
```

needs to changed in (keeping it here in one line since it cannot be written in two lines):

```
Public Sub NewWindow2(ByRef pDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean) Implements DWebBrowserEvents2.NewWindow2
    Me._Browser.OnNewWindow2(pDisp, cancel)
End Sub
```

I also suggest to keep the [MarshalAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute) attributes you found in the C# sample code.
For example, in the `DWebBrowserEvents2` Interface definition, change:

```
<ComImport(), Guid("34A715A0-6587-11D0-924A-0020AFC7AC4D"), [...]
Public Interface DWebBrowserEvents2
    '[...]
    <DispId(251)> _
    Sub NewWindow2(ByRef pDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean)
End Interface
```

in:

```
<ComImport(), Guid("34A715A0-6587-11D0-924A-0020AFC7AC4D"), [...]
Public Interface DWebBrowserEvents2
    '[...]
    <DispId(251)>
    Sub NewWindow2(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)> ByRef pDisp As Object, ByRef cancel As Boolean)
End Interface
```

---

▶ Note that, when you receive a notification as *the class must implement...*, you can select the member that is underlined and press <kbd>ALT+ENTER</kbd> to let Visual Studio implement the interfaces for you.

Comment: I use ReSharper so I'm not always sure what functionality it provides and what comes from VS but, if I'm not mistaken, if you declare a class and then specify an interface to implement, VS actually prompts you to have it add the method implementations, which includes the appropriate clauses.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, it does. If you copy paste the code or use a conversion tool (that doesn't add the keyword, for some reason), you can always use the `ALT+ENTER` thing I mentioned, since - if you let VS do it - it duplicates everything.

Comment: That depends on the conversion tool. This is an example of why I recommend [Instant VB](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/csharp-to-vb-converter.html), which does a thorough analysis and, as long as the interface is part of the code being converted, will add the `Implements` clauses to the methods.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your help. Following jmcilhinney suggestions i thought about cancel part of code unnecessary, ...But you discovered another issue. ...So i leave full code. Thank You Jimi.

Comment: @jmcilhinney By default, if you type `Implements <some interface>` and hit enter, Visual Studio will create stubs for all of the interface members.  As I recall, it's the same as what you would get if you chose "Implement Interface" in C# (vs. "Implement Interface Explicitly" which doesn't have a direct equivalent in VB).